# How to install nodejs and npm with Chef so users other than root can use it

Tags: node.js, npm, chef-infra

Great, so I've got node and npm installed with Chef. But I can't use it unless I'm root because Chef does everything as root and apparently npm doesn't know how to handle that. The docs are silent on what to do about this, and everywhere else I've looked recommends changing the permissions of ~/.npm (which would mean changing the permissions of the root user's ~/.npm), which feels really wrong.

What is the correct installation procedure to allow all users on a box to use npm without getting a ton of these errors:

```
npm ERR! Error: Attempt to unlock selenium-webdriver@^2.44.0, which hasn't been locked
```

Comment: Are you having trouble using `npm` as an unprivileged user without the `-g` or `--global` option? Or is it only when you use the `-g` or `--global` option?

Comment: @Trott i'm just trying to execute `npm install` on a project

Comment: How are you passing the "npm install" command to chef? Are you using the execute resource?

Comment: Are you using a cookbook to install node and npm or did you use apt?

Answer (score 2):

First off let me make sure i understand your scenario correctly

- You have installed Node.js
- You have installed NPM
- You have laid down your Node.js project and wish to install its dependencies with NPM *(those defined in your package.json)*

If I've understood you correctly there, then you will want to invoke the npm command as the target user, and with the current working directory set to your project directory where the `package.json` file exists.

You can do this with an execute block, though you will need to find a way to define when it should execute. Depending on how fine-grain your deployment is you could for instance base it off of package.json changing such as this:

```
cookbook_file 'package.json' do
  source 'package.json'
  notifies :run, 'execute[npm_install]', :immediately
end

execute 'npm_install' do
  command 'npm install'
  user 'nodejs'
  cwd '/opt/nodejs/myapp/'
  action :nothing
end
```

This way any time your package.json file changes it will rerun the npm install command, but otherwise will not so it would be safe to run continuously.

*the `execute` resource is one of the few that are not idempotent*

The process will be spawned as the nodejs user in this case *(which would have to exist at execution time)* so any resources headed to `~/.npm` would go to `/home/nodejs/.npm` and should be owned by that user and its primary group.

If you aren't able to run the npm command as the limited user, so long as you have the appropriate permissions, you could add `sudo` to the command to allow `npm install` to run as the limited user, with the elevation

Edit: I just noticed this question is two years old....